# Google Sign-In via Firebase: GIDSignInDelegate does not conform to ViewController

Tags: swift, firebase, google-authentication, google-signin, firebase-authentication

I'm introducing Google Sign-In to my app and whilst both Google and Firebase documentation is thorough enough, what I have done as they suggested is not sufficient... I am still getting this error. Hopefully this will help others with finding a solution to the problem when implementing their SDK....thanks in advance for reviewing this chunky one:

[image: Error Image]

Here's the [Firebase guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/login/google.html) and the [Google guide:](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in?ver=swift)

So

1. Added **Google to podfile** - CHECK
2. Added line into **Bridging-Header** - CHECK
3. Added **GoogleService-Info.plist** & bundle identifier & reversed client ID  to **URL schemes** - CHECK
4. **App Delegate** has the following, with no errors but I notice there are likely to be conflicts between Facebook login (working correctly) and newly Google, which I've no idea how to handle together:

   [image: Code added to AppDelegate - sorry not written in here, StackOverflow formatting was hating me on this occasion]

   **P.S.** I have NOT added GIDSignInDelegate to AppDelegate here because I am planning for my VC to handle the login logic, as you will see below...
5. **LoginVC ViewController** code here:

   ```
   class LoginVC: UIViewController, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate, UITextViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate, GIDSignInUIDelegate {

       override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       let ref = Firebase(url: "https://MYAPPID.firebaseio.com")
       GIDDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
       GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
       GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signInSilently()  // for if the user has recently been authenticated
       }
   ```

Then this, which from what I can see... should be everything Google needs to talk to Firebase:

```
        // Implementing the required GIDSignInDelegate methods
        func googleSignIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInForUser user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: NSError!) {
            if (error == nil) {
                // Auth with Firebase
                let userId = user.userID
                let idToken = user.authentication.idToken
                let fullName = user.profile.name
                let givenName = user.profile.givenName
                let familyName = user.profile.familyName
                let email = user.profile.email
                ref.authWithOAuthProvider("google", token: user.authentication.accessToken, withCompletionBlock: { (error, authData) in
                    // User is logged in!
                })
            } else {
                print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }


        func googleSignOut() {
            GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signOut()
            ref.unauth()
        }

        // Implement the required GIDSignInDelegate methods and Unauth when disconnected from Google
        func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didDisconnectWithUser user:GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: NSError!) {
            ref.unauth()
        }


        // IBAction to handle the sign-in process
        @IBAction func googleButtonPressed(sender: TKTransitionSubmitButton!) {
            GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
        }
```

Baffled? Sorry for the long one guys...but I've done everything the Firebase guide suggests and that means the logic in the Google doc for AppDelegate is all there in the ProfileVC. Any pointers?

Comment: I'm learning iOS programming myself and just got the google sign working today. My guess is this is a problem with the GISSignInDelegate although you said you took care of it. My suggestion is to start with a clean project, follow the tutorial on google literally until you get it running, then you can change stuff all you want

Comment: Yeah Ive since gotten it working with the new firebase, thanks!

Comment: Same issue when updating to swift 3.

Comment: did you find a solution for this? encountered this issue when migrating my project to Swift 3

Answer (score 5):

It's saying your class have not implemented required method for your `GIDSignInDelegate`. There are major change in name of method in Swift 3. So your new method will be

> public func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user:
>   GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: NSError!)

Please check Library screen shot. So `In` is missing in new swift 3 convention of naming of methods or classes.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I found needed methods by typing "func s" and searching in suggestions box

Oh, I miss Alt+Enter feature in Android Studio

(BTW this is for Swift 3 in XCode 8 beta)

```
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: NSError!) {
        let authentication = user.authentication
        let credential = FIRGoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: (authentication?.idToken)!,
                                                          accessToken: (authentication?.accessToken)!)
        let comp:FIRAuthResultCallback = { (user:FIRUser?, error:NSError?) in
            if error == nil {
                DataStorage.inst.user.id = user?.uid
            }
        }
        FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(with: credential, completion: comp)
    }

    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didDisconnectWith user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: NSError!) {

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just replace

```
func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInForUser user: GIDGoogleUser!,
withError error: NSError!) {
    if (error == nil) {
        // Perform any operations on signed in user here.

    } else {
        print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
    }}
```

with

```
public func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
    //Code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add

`#import "GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignIn.h"`

to your Bridging header file and hit shift + cmd + k to clean.

Answer (score -1):

Go to: Link Binary with Libraries. Then, Click on Add, then Add Other. Press "Cmd + shift + G". Then, type: "/usr/lib". Then, Click on "libz.1.dylib". Press Ok to add and the errors will go away. Also, you are probably not completing all the functions that come along with this protocol. You will have to add following:

```
func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInForUser user: GIDGoogleUser!,
    withError error: NSError!) {
        if (error == nil) {
            // Perform any operations on signed in user here.

        } else {
            print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
}

func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didDisconnectWithUser user:GIDGoogleUser!,
    withError error: NSError!) {
        // Perform any operations when the user disconnects from app here.
        // ...
}
```

Also, make sure you have added the foll. line in Bridging Header.

```
#import <GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignIn.h>
```

UPDATE: 
GIDSignInDelegate can't be added to View Controller. Instead, you should add "GIDSignInUIDelegate" in VC and try to perform other(Gidsigndwlwgate) operations in App Delegate. It will work.

Comment: As you'll see above, I have these items of code already in my VC. I tried the "libz.1..." library but I believe this is for Google Analytics and not necessary anyway. Regardless, none of the changes you mentioned are a solution to my problem.

Comment: I like your optimism, but this does not resolve the issue.... it just transfers the problem to AppDelegate: "Type AppDelegate does not confirm to protocol 'GIDSignInDelegate'. If it could not be used inside of a VC, why would the Firebase documentation show it that way?

Comment: Actually, I don't know how as I am also just working on my first ever such app integration, but now, it is working. Did you add the following lines in viewDidLoad() ? GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes.append("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login")
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes.append("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me")