# Cannot assign value of type 'AppDelegate' to type 'GIDSignInDelegate!"

Tags: ios, swift3, google-plus, xcode8

#### Cannot assign value of type 'AppDelegate' to type 'GIDSignInDelegate!'

- I have added both -
     #import 
     #import 
  in the Bridging header file.
- I have installed the google SDK from cocoapods '/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0/lib/cocoapods.rb'
- This is the AppDelegate declaration - 
  class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GIDSignInUIDelegate {

#### Step 2: Describe your environment

- xcode 8
- iOS 10

Observed Results:

- Compiler Error - Cannot assign value of type 'AppDelegate' to type 'GIDSignInDelegate!'

Relevant Code:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
// Override point for customization after application launch.
self.initialize()
IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enable = true
TimeSyncManager.sharedInstance.syncTimeWithServer(withNotifcationOption: false)
AppScreenManager.sharedInstance.setUpInitialScreen()
SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
//setUpGoogleSDK()

var configureError: NSError?
GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
assert(configureError == nil, "Error configuring Google services: \(configureError)")

GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self      //<<--------Error at this Point

application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) {
  (granted, error) in
  //Parse errors and track state
}
return true
```

Now the problem I face is that Appdelegate shows error that- 
Type 'AppDelegate' does not conform to protocol 'GIDSignInDelegate'

My AppDelegate Code is

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate {
var window: UIWindow?
public func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!){
}


// Finished disconnecting |user| from the app successfully if |error| is |nil|.
public func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didDisconnectWith user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!){

}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have implemented `GIDSignInUIDelegate` instead of `GIDSignInDelegate`. Simply implement the `GIDSignInDelegate` will remove the compile error.

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate {
```

Don't forgot to implement methods of `GIDSignInDelegate` with `AppDelegate`.

```
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didDisconnectWith user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {

}

func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {

}
```

Comment: Yes it worked, 
Thanks and sorry for the late reply.

Comment: But now on implementing both the protocol functions it says AppDelegate does not conforms to GIDSignInDelegate.
`code`

Comment: @RamandeepSinghGosal Don't add code in comment it is hard to read it, edit your question with App delegate code.

Comment: Hey thanks for so much help @nirav
I have edited the question with the strange protocol conformation error I am facing.

Comment: @RamandeepSinghGosal Try once removing public prefix from the method and also clean build the project once.

Comment: Removed public, cleaned build, deleted derived data even restarted xcode.
but in vein, 
Have you checked it on xcode 8 ?
It gave me this strange error for facebook sdk too. 
but automatically got resolved afterwards.

Comment: @RamandeepSinghGosal Check this one once http://stackoverflow.com/a/38031525/6433023

Comment: Nope its not working its not recognising the delegates.

Comment: There is nothing I am able to find out till date to resolve the issue

Comment: @RamandeepSinghGosal Have you set the delegate properly because same thing is working for me or Are you still getting error for delegate ?

Comment: Yes the same thing is working on my fellow developers xcode but not on mine.
Not able to understand what is wrong. 
I ll delete the pod and reinstall everything from the beginning to check it for once.

Comment: I got the right answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43775558/appdelegate-does-not-conform-to-protocol-gidsignindelegate/44303064#44303064). 
There was an error class created by my fellow developer and compiler was not able to check which error class to refer to for **GIDSignInDelegate** methods.
Make sure you all are also not doing the same silly mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement GIDSignInDelegate in AppDelegate

```
 class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate {

  func googleSignIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInForUser user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: NSError!) {

  }


  func googleSignOut() {

  }

  // Implement the required GIDSignInDelegate methods and Unauth when disconnected from Google

  func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didDisconnectWithUser user:GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: NSError!) {

  }


}
```