# 'AppDelegate' does not conform to protocol 'GIDSignInDelegate'

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

I am Trying to implement Google Signin in swift-3 but I am having a very strange error I am following the link https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in?ver=swift . But I see this error everytime I do Implement it again and again.
I have added the following in bridging header.

```
#import <Google/SignIn.h>
```

I have installed the pod GoogleSignin  `pod 'Google/SignIn'`

This is my AppDelegate File code

```
    class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate {   //<--Here it gives the error
        //Method implemented but giving the error
        func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
        //TODO
        }
    }
```

'AppDelegate' does not conform to protocol 'GIDSignInDelegate'

I 've tried reinstalling pods

I've tried cleaning and other things but nope noting helped.

Comment: I think you should read about Protocols and Delegates.

Comment: You haven't added `didDisconnectWith` method of `GIDSignInDelegate` delegate

Comment: @UmairAfzal Well I have read about delegates and protocols and there is a word "optional" written in front of `didDisconnectWith` method and that means it is not mandatory to use that method.
@NiravD using it does not make any difference.
problem remains the same

Comment: One thing I see is that when I click on `GIDSignInDelegate` Sometimes it takes me to the Swift file and sometimes it takes me to the objective-c file.
I think the compiler is not able to understand that from where it has to pick the protocol.
Any idea about this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just spent 3 hours on this. The correct signature you need to implement is :

`func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!)`

But - **check whether you are not overriding the definition of `Error` in your app** (or the other classes `GIDSignIn`, `GIDGoogleUser`). I had a custom `Error` class in my app which has overridden the default `Error` class. After I renamed my `Error` class, the problem went away.

Swift compiler was not very helpful here, because it displayed the type as `Error` for both cases in the error message, while not indicating they both mean different `Error` types.

The lesson is to not use names already used in Foundation for my classes.

Comment: Yes I also had the same problem It was the Error class which was created by fellow developer. and I had been struggling like for days. Well I got it resolved but did not get the time to update it here. 
and yes this was the solution to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

you need to add following two method in appdelegate

```
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didDisconnectWith user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {

}

func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {

}
```

Comment: I have implemented the method didSignInFor and yes that was the only mandatory one.
other one was optional.
I have implemented that method ...
also shown in code snippet above but it says the mothod is not implemented then autocorrect tell me to add the method I click enter the same method is added again and then it says invalid redeclaration of the method.
I remove one again it says does not CONFIRM to the protocol.

Answer (score 0):

You must have to implement all required method of `GIDSignInDelegate` to remove this error. So check the list of method in `GIDSignInDelegate` protocol and implement in the AppDelegate class.

And in `didFinsishLaunchingOption` method set the delegate as:

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
```

Comment: I have implemented all the required methods (only one is present there).
Also I implemented the optional one but it did not solve the problem.

Comment: did you set the  delegate of the GIDSignIn in  the AppDelegate class ?

Comment: Try to set import statement for GoogleSingIn in AppDelegate:import GoogleSignIn

Comment: That is done already.
Otherwise it does not recognize GidSignInDelegate

Comment: @RamandeepSinghGosal, did u found the solution, I am also facing this issue.

Comment: Well yes it was a very silly mistake, I had a custom class named Error in my code and It caused the issue as the GidSignInDelegate method was not able to recognize which error class to refer to. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43775558/appdelegate-does-not-conform-to-protocol-gidsignindelegate) is the link for another question that I asked and had it answered.

Answer (score -1):

Well it was a very silly mistake, I had a custom class named Error in my code and It caused the issue as the GidSignInDelegate method was not able to recognize which error class to refer to. Anyone looking for the answer please cross check it if you have made the same silly mistake.

Comment: I don't understand down voting of this comment.